# Remove duplicates from one list only

Tags: compare

I have 2 lists as plain text. One list contains all the email adresses of customers I mailed in the past. The other list is a list of potential customers I want to mail.
I find this hard to explain in english, so hopefully you'll get it once you look at the example below.

```
LIST A: List of customers I already sent email to (addresses from this list should never be outputted):
michael@aaa.nl
michael@bbb.nl
michael@ccc.nl
michael@ddd.nl (shouldn't be outputted, even though it is not in LIST B)

LIST B: List of customers I want to mail:
michael@aaa.nl (duplicate, exists in LIST A)
michael@bbb.nl (duplicate, exists in LIST A)
martin@ccc.nl  (duplicate, domain ccc.nl exists in LIST A)
michael@fff.nl (not duplicate, I want to output this)

Result I want:
michael@fff.nl
```

Is there a script / commando (OSX or Linux) to get this to work? I hope that you guys can help me out?

I tried things with uniq and diff, but I cannot get the output of one list (B) only.

Answer (score 0):

I just googled `compare two lists online tool` and found this: http://www.listdiff.com/compare-2-lists-difference-tool

But it doesn't compare domains. That would require developing a custom script in Node.js or Python or almost anything. I don't think there is a ready script for this, but it would be possible to compare it in few lines of code...